# How to reference an existing resource item in azure template variable

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to reference existing resource (static IP address) in the ARM template

```
"variables":{
"WebPublicIPName": "[reference('/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/PANAZ-GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/VPNPublicIP-Dev_B')]"}
```

But I am getting following error: *Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'WebPublicIPName' is not valid: The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use reference function in a variable, so this is not possible.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, there might be different ways to solve whatever you are trying to solve

Comment: I'm trying to use existing resource, not created as part of the template

Comment: to use existing resource you need `resourceId()` function to reference existing resource - just put the reference function into new resource, not into variables section